# I want to fetch and display users info on page from db when someone goes to the url https://example.com/{username}

Tags: php, web-applications

I have user information in the database table. I want to fetch and display the user's info on the page from DB when someone goes to the URL `https://example.com/{username}`. But I am confused about how to get it done since the `https://example.com/{username}` page doesn't exist. I am using PHP and MySQL. I am in the learning phase. It would be nice if someone could tell me what I need to get this done and what am I supposed to learn for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try -> [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)
Let us know about your progress.

Comment: Don't get so hursh Anth, LOL...  Abhishek, it's not about PHP, but about the web server. Mostly you are on Apache and Apache has a host level configuration file called .htaccess, where you can tell the web server, that if it gets a request for a particular formatted url, then to which script it should redirect the request. This is called URL rewriting. Read about it on internet and I am sure you will be good to go.